# get path from file calling batch

Tags: java, batch-file

Hy there. I have a simple question regarding batch files.
Lets say I have made a simple batch file which I have set up to be the standard program to open .txt files. Now I open a exemple.txt file and my batch file gets called, but **how can I get information about which file just called the batch file?**

Background information:
I have written a text tool in java and would like to be able to doubleclick on a .txt file and open it up with my java tool. Since I have been told that this is not possible, I am trying to use batch as the helper to call java.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, that will normally be the first argument of the script. That would be `"$1"` with the shell, no idea about windows batch files however (`%1`?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mr. fge's answer was golden. Thank you so much!

> %1

gives the path of the file calling it.

And for those who are interested in calling a jar file with the path as the argument:

```
@echo off
start javaw -jar "C:\Users\YourJarFile.jar" %1
```

PS: make sure to have a static path to your jar file, otherwise it will attempt to reach the jar file from the %1 path..